# Check if variable is defined and checking its property in the same conditional in PugJS

Tags: node.js, conditional-statements, pug

I'm supplying a variable `items` to a pug view, and I want to present the same result for the case where the variable is either an empty list or `undefined`.

I'd expect that this can be done with the `&` operator like

```
if typeof(items) != 'undefined' & items.length > 0
    each item in items
        p item
else
    p no items here :(
```

but based on the error message for when `items` is either missing or `undefined`, pug is evaluating both sides of `&` operator.

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

An obvious solution is to perform this check in the JS calling the view, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in a single conditional in pug.

Comment: Note that the AND operator in javascript is _two_ ampersands (`&&`) not just a single one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript [logical AND operator (`&&`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) is written with two ampersands. Revising the conditional to this should work (parentheses included for readability):

```
if (typeof(items) !== 'undefined') && (items.length > 0)
  each item in items
    p item
else
  p no items here :(
```